# 2D Particle Simulation in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, particle-system

I want to make an iOS app that has ~100 particles that each move or operate on their own with similar sets of rules, and interact with each other.

I'm not really sure where I should begin developing for this, is there a framework out there that handles 2-dimensional position and velocity vectors that is compatible with Swift 3?

What's the best way to animate this? I'm semi familiar with metal, done a few tutorials, and all the particles would really have to be are small colored circles.

I'm very familiar with UIKit and SpriteKit, but I'm not sure if those will apply at all to this.

Edit: Perhaps I'm not looking for particle systems at all and may have been mistaken. What I'm trying to do is make a simulation of multiple different objects that follow each others speed and direction, creating a "hive mind" like group of many objects. This is meant more for a little learning project than anything

Comment: SpriteKit has a very easy to use particle emitter and even lets you edit is visually. You can use SpriteKit inside a view by using an instance of SKView. Add it to your app and inside the SKView it will run the SpriteKit engine.

Comment: @Fogmeister I looked into it, but doesn't seem to be exactly what I mean. Take a look at my edit and see if that makes sense what I'm looking for

Comment: what you're looking for is `boids` or `emergent behaviour`.

Comment: http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/swift-metal-four-million-particles-on.html  you can check flexmonkey's blog and github, though not clear whether this is what you're looking for.